# Calling java function from .py file in Pydev

Tags: java, python, eclipse, pydev, jython

I have a file.py as follows :

```
import unittest
from  com.bahmanm import Greeter


class A(unittest.TestCase, Greeter):
def test_A(self):
    self.greet("Bahman")

if __name__ == "__main__":  
unittest.main()
```

In above case, Greeter is a java file as:

```
package  com.bahmanm;
public class Greeter 
{

    private String msg;

    public Greeter() 
    {
        msg = "Hello, ";
    }

    public void greet(String name)
    {
        System.out.println(msg + name);
    }
}
```

The code executes successfully, but I am not able to navigate from python code to java code (in PyDev) at line **self.greet("Bahman"**) in the file.py code.

Though, I am able to view the contents of Greeter file from line 
**from com.bahmanm import Greeter**.  But unable to check the code flow at the function call.

I am using **jython** interpreter *(grammar 2.5, default interpreter,jython.jar 2.5.3)*. I have also added the Java src path to **PYTHONPATH** in Eclipse. Also I have added Java project in the 
PYTHON PROJECT->RIGHT CLICK->PROPERTIES-> PROJECT REFERENCES

Any suggestion regarding the above navigation will be of great help.

Comment: So the code works but the IDE navigation short cuts don't work?

Comment: Yes, the code executes perfectly fine. If I use Greeter.greet("Bahman") in python file, I am able to navigate to the Java source code but navigation via self.greet("Bahman") fails.